# Draw line between 2 elements in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a flights agency website, and at some point I need to draw some lines between elements that are being added dynamically.

See the image to understand what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Let's suppose that for each departure and destination there are 2 divs, One for departure and one for destination!

**Example:**
*The below elements will be added to the DOM dynamically depending on the API response for flights.*

```html
<!--First flight-->

<div className="flight">
    <div className="element">Bucharest<div>
    <!--image element here-->
    <div className="element">Tenerife<div>
</div>


<!--Second flight-->

<div className="flight">
    <div className="element">Tenerife<div>
     <!--image element here-->
    <div className="element">Bucharest<div>
</div>
```

I found some Javascript solutions but I need to specify which elements are concerned which I cannot do in my case cause the elements are being added dynamically depending on the amount of flights.

I would be preferable to find a solution with only CSS but I think that might be impossible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<hr` element in HTML. This draws a line between the two elements.

You can see more information about it on

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr